# O que são princípios de Usabilidade?

Tags: ux, usabilidade

No Design de Interfaces e de Interação, o que são (e quais são) os princípios de Usabilidade?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Princípios de Usabilidade (também chamados de Heurísticas) são guias ou "conselhos de especialistas" a respeito de boas práticas no design de interfaces com o usuário. Eles advém de um método chamado Avaliação Heurística ([proposto por Jakob Nielsen em 1990](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=97281)) e servem para dois propósitos: facilitar a escolha entre diferentes alternativas de design  durante a criação e permitir encontrar e justificar problemas durante a avaliação.

As heurísticas mais famosas para o design de interfaces em softwares de uso geral foram propostas por Nielsen e são compostas de 10 princípios:

- **Visibilidade do sistema**. Sempre mantenha os usuários informados sobre o que acontece no sistema, por meio de *feedback* apropriado no momento certo. Recursos que podem ser utilizados para isso incluem alterações no cursor do mouse, realce (*highlight*) de seleções, barra de informações (*status bar*). Mas, deve-se evitar exageros ou interações desnecessárias como no exemplo abaixo (os resultados poderiam ser imediatamente exibidos sem a necessidade do clique no botão):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Correspondência entre o sistema e o mundo real**. Fale a lingua do usuário, utilizando palavras, frases e conceitos que lhe são familiar ao contrário de termos técnicos. Termos técnicos e mesmo metáforas podem ser enganadores. O exemplo abaixo é ilustrativo (e engraçado), pois a interpretação de "type" (que em inglês pode significar sigifica a palavra "tipo" ou o verbo "digite") pode levar um usuário a digitar M-I-S-M-A-T-C-H no teclado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Controle e liberdade para o usuário**. Forneça opções para que os usuários facilmente escapem de condições inesperadas, usando "saídas de emergência" claramente indicadas. Para alcançar isso, forneça a opção de desfazer (*undo*) ações e permita que operações longas sejam canceladas. Mas faça isso de forma clara, provavelmente fornecendo diretamente uma opção de cancelamento. Mesmo o diálogo abaixo é confuso porque não apresenta um botão chamado "Cancelar" e ainda apresenta a indicação textual usando palavras que não se encontram nos botões apresentados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Consistência e padrões**. Evite fazer com que os usuários precisem pensar a respeito de diferentes palavras, situações ou ações que possam ter o mesmo significado. A ideia é manter a mesma aparência e comportamento (*look and feel*) em todo o sistema, para que coisas similares pareçam similares e coisas diferentes pareçam diferentes. Pode parecer simples, mas é um erro muito comum como no exemplo abaixo envolvendo o posicionamento de botões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Diagnóstico e recuperação de erros**. Use linguagem simples, construtiva e polida para descrever a natureza de um problema e sugerir uma forma de solucioná-lo. O exemplo abaixo chama o usuário de idiota, aumentando a sua frustração com o desentendimento da interface e prejudicando imensamente sua experiência com o produto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Prevenção de erros**. Sempre que possível, previna a ocorrência de erros antes de tudo. Isso pode ser feito desabilitando-se comandos temporariamente inacessíveis ou ilegais e usando caixas de seleção (como combos e listas) ao invés de caixas de texto, pois elas são menos propensas a erros porque o usuário não tem como errar na grafia do conteúdo. Ainda assim, isso não deve ser utilizado ao extremo como nesse exemplo (em que não há ganho de precisão de entrada de dados, mas há perda na eficiência da execução da tarefa):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Reconhecimento ao invés de recordação**. Faça objetos, ações e opções serem visíveis. Isso significa que os componentes gráficos devem ser usados da forma convencionada (seleção por combos e listas e não por caixas de texto, por exemplo) e deve-se evitar solicitar que o usuário mantenha muita informação em memória. No exemplo abaixo, assim que o usuário clicar em OK, todo o caminho indicado será imediatamente eliminado da tela, mas se essa informação é importante ela deveria permanecer indicada visualmente (com o uso de balões ou a abertura automática da janela indicada):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Flexibilidade e eficiência no uso**. Forneça aceleradores que são invisíveis para usuários novatos, mas que permitem usuários experientes a executar suas tarefas mais rapidamente. Exemplos clássicos são as teclas de atalho e os menus de acesso rápido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Design e estética minimalistas**. Evite usar informação que é irrelevante ou raramente utilizada. Adicionalmente, use cores e fontes simples e fáceis de serem compreendidas, e organize os elementos para ocuparem espaços condizentes com suas funções (isto é, não apresente informação desconectada em uma mesma janela). No exemplo abaixo, as barras de comandos demonstram más e boas práticas de agrupamento de botões, e a janela demonstra uma má prática na exibição de informação não relacionada em uma única visão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Ajuda e documentação**. Forneça meios para que informação possa ser facilmente buscada e forneça ajuda em passos concretos que possam ser facilmente seguidos. Exemplos clássicos de boas práticas são a ajuda de contexto (em que o usuário utiliza F1, uma tecla convencionada, para exibir informação a respeito do campo atualmente selecionado) e balões de informação que indicam o elemento visual a que se relacionam.

É importante mencionar que esses são alguns dos princípios de Usabilidade clássicos utilizados no desenvolvimento de software (há outros mencionados [no artigo da Wikipedia sobre avaliação heurística](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_evaluation)<sup>en</sup>), mas que a escolha de um conjunto de heurísticas *definitivo* é passível de discussão, principalmente porque sua aplicabilidade depende fortemente do domínio da aplicação.

Em jogos digitais (video games), por exemplo, certos aspectos de Usabilidade são menos importantes ou são intencionalmente não atendidos porque se almeja produzir a Experiência de Usuário (UX) de diversão. Por exemplo, certos elementos de jogos são construídos para serem intencionalmente mais difíceis de serem executados ou lembrados, ainda que outros aspectos como feedback permaneçam importantes. Assim, no caso de produtos para entretenimento existem heurísticas mais famosas, baseadas nas heurísticas utilitárias classicas mas extendendo-as para inclusão de aspectos hedonicos (não utilitários).

Um primeiro exemplo é a taxonomia do [modelo MDA](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~hunicke/MDA.pdf) (de *Model-Design-Aesthetics*) que inclui os seguintes princípios relacionados a estática da diversão:

- **Sensação**. Jogo como prazer sensorial.
- **Fantasia**. Jogo como faz-de-conta.
- **Narrativa**. Jogo como drama.
- **Desafio**. Jogo como curso de obstáculos.
- **Companheirismo**. Jogo como arcabouço social.
- **Descoberta**. Jogo como território inexplorado.
- **Expressão**. Jogo como auto-descoberta.
- **Submissão**. Jogo como passatempo.

E outro exemplo famoso é o modelo [GameFlow](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1077253), baseado na [teoria da Experiência Ótima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) (Flow) e que inclui entre outras heurísticas as seguines (os detalhes são acessíveis no paper referenciado):

- **Concentração**. Jogos devem prover estímulos de diferentes origens e que sejam significativos para a atenção do jogador. Os jogadores devem ser capazes de manter o foco na tarefa, sem ser sobrecarregados com muita informação, e não devem ser distraídos das tarefas que desejam ou precisam executar.
- **Desafio**. Desafio em jogos devem estar de acordo com o nível de habilidade dos jogadores, fornecer diferentes níveis de dificuldade e prover feedback no progresso da realização dos objetivos.
- **Controle**. Jogadores devem ser capazes de escolher seus objetivos e ações e se sentir responsáveis pelos resultados do jogo. Eles não devem ser capazes de cometer erros que quebrem sua imersão na fantasia e narrativa.

---

Fontes principais:

- [Preece, Rogers e Sharp. Interaction Design: Beyond Human - Computer Interaction](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP001645.html).
- [Interface Hall of Shame (fonte das imagens)](http://www.interfacehallofshame.eu/www.iarchitect.com/shame.htm)
- [Miller. Lecture 5 on Heuristic Evaluation](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.893/F03/lectures/L5.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

Muito já se discutiu sobre as 10 Heurísticas de Nielsen voltadas a Usabilidade, não tenho por pretensão re-descobrir a roda. Pelo contrário, quero trazer também aos meus posts tais premissas e ressaltar a sua importância.
O meu objetivo com esse post é poder tratar dessas Heurísticas em outros posts e poder referenciá-las através de link, facilitando assim o entendimento.

Mas afinal,  falando rapidamente, o que é Heurística?
Essa palavra tem origem grega, heurísko, e tem a mesma base etmológica que  Eureka, em resumo, ela está associada ao descobrimento.
É importante entender isso porque tal palavra para muitos é mais um palavrão, quando tratamos do assunto em alguns debates e falamos “heurística” há aqueles que por desconhecerem o termo nos olham desconfiados, como se estivéssemos a usar uma palavra esquisita a fim de justificar um conhecimento “superior”. E não é isso, trata-se de uma palavra que exemplifica bem o que é feito no campo da Usabilidade, dia após dia descobrimos os caminhos corretos para o desenvolvimento de sistemas, apps, sites, etc. E muitas vezes durante o processo de criação temos o nosso insight, onde facilmente poderíamos gritar Eureka. Agora, porque reinventar a roda se podemos de fato seguir algumas premissas daqueles que vieram antes de nós e com base em estudo chegaram a conclusões… heurísticas.  ;)
De acordo com Jackob Nielsen.
“Estes são os dez princípios gerais do design de interface do usuário. Eles são chamados de “heurística”, porque estão mais na natureza de regras do que como diretrizes de usabilidade específicos.” 
Esclarecendo, é um visão para o próprio estudo, do que uma diretriz única e imutável.
1. Visibilidade do status do sistema
O sistema deve sempre manter os usuários informados sobre o que está acontecendo, através de feedback apropriado e em tempo razoável.

1. Correspondência entre o sistema e o mundo real
   O sistema deve falar a linguagem dos usuários, com palavras, frases e conceitos familiares ao usuário, ao invés de termos orientados ao sistema. Siga convenções do mundo real, tornando as informações que aparecem em uma ordem natural e lógica.
2. Controle do usuário e liberdade
   Usuários freqüentemente escolhem algumas funções do sistema por engano e vão precisar sempre de uma “saída de emergência” claramente marcada para sair daquele estado indesejado sem ter que passar por um extenso “diálogo”. Apoio ao desfazer e refazer.
3. Consistência e padrões
   Os usuários não precisam adivinhar que diferentes palavras, situações ou ações significam a mesma coisa. Siga as convenções da plataforma.
4. Prevenção de erros
   Ainda melhor do que boas mensagens de erro é um projeto cuidadoso que impede que em primeiro lugar esse erro possa ocorrer.  Eliminando as condições passíveis de erros ou verificá-las, apresentado aos usuários uma opção de confirmação antes de se comprometerem com uma determinada ação.
5. Reconhecimento em vez de recordação
   Minimizar a carga de memória do usuário tornando objetos, ações e opções visíveis. O usuário não deve ter que se lembrar da informação de uma parte do diálogo para outra. Instruções de uso do sistema devem estar visíveis e serem facilmente recuperáveis quando necessário.
6. Flexibilidade e eficiência de utilização
   Aceleradores – invisíveis para o usuário novato – podem frequentemente acelerar a interação para o usuário experiente, que o sistema pode atender a ambos os usuários inexperientes e experientes. Permitir aos usuários personalizar ações freqüentes.
7. Estética e design minimalista
   Os diálogos não devem conter informações irrelevantes ou raramente necessárias. Cada unidade extra de informação em um diálogo compete com as unidades relevantes de informação e diminui sua visibilidade relativa.
8. Ajude os usuários a reconhecer, diagnosticar e resolver erros
   Mensagens de erros devem ser expressas em linguagem clara (sem códigos), indicar com precisão o problema e construtivamente sugerir uma solução.
9. Ajuda e documentação
   Mesmo que seja melhor que um sistema possa ser usado sem documentação, pode ser necessário fornecer uma ajuda e documentação. Qualquer informação deve ser fácil de se pesquisada, com foco na atividade do usuário, lista de passos concretos a serem realizados, e não ser muito grande.

Retirado de: http://www.dclick.com.br/2012/02/12/heuristica/