# Planejamento de interface de usuário

Tags: gui, ux

Já tentei desenvolver a parte de *layout* de algumas aplicações, mas o único critério que eu sempre usei foi verificar se está ficando bonito ou não. Acontece que esse critério não é muito util e poucas vezes me levou a desenvolver alguma coisa boa.

Ao desenvolver uma interface de usuário para uma aplicação web, quais são os critérios considerados? Quais são os pontos que preciso levantar para poder tomar decisões mais precisas no desenvolvimento de um *layout*?

Answer (score 12):

De uma forma bem simples e direta, eu diria que são três os critérios que precisariam ser observados:

### 1. Funcionalidade

Se a sua aplicação web é um sistema comercial ou científico, é natural que o mais importante seja a funcionalidade. Ou seja, a interface deve permitir que o usuário a utilize para alcançar um ou mais objetivos práticos (isto é, resolver o problema). Se ela não servir pra isso, perde completamente todo o seu propósito. Assim, o planejamento da interface deve considerear como ofertar tais serviços: por exemplo, campos de entrada para os dados que são necessários, botões para a execução de ações, etc.

### 2. Usabilidade

Além do caráter funcional, é importante também que a interface seja suficientemente bem feita para que seja facilmente "utilizável" pelo usuário. Isso envolve vários aspectos (sugiro ler também [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27099/o-que-s%C3%A3o-princ%C3%ADpios-de-usabilidade)) com a intenção de tornar a interação fácil, segura e eficiente. Um projetista experiente consegue embuir seu planejamento de interface com boas práticas, mas é sempre útil avaliar esse projeto com pessoas reais, representativas do tipo de usuário do sistema intencionado, para que problemas sejam percebidos o mais rapidamente possível. É, por isso, uma prática comum a realização de testes com protótipos de baixa fidelidade (feitos em papel, mesmo) para testar ideias de interação, metáforas, restrições lógicas, etc.

### 3. Experiência

Muito além da usabilidade (que tem um caráter pragmático sobre a interação ser fácil, sucinta, eficiente, etc), há também a tendência em se preocupar com o caráter "hedônico" da interação. Por hedônico entendem-se questões mais subjetivas como apelo, preferência, gosto, e até mesmo diversão. Em aplicações de entretenimento esse "requisito" é muito óbvio, mas cada vez mais percebe-se que essa é uma necessidade grande também em sistemas comerciais e científicos, principalmente quando o uso é opcional (*discretionary*) ou requer sustentação (intenciona-se manter a atenção do usuário por períodos prolongados). Nesses casos, os testes com protótipos também servem para avaliar as preferências estéticas, o potencial de apelo, a curiosidade gerada por certos aspectos da interface, e até a satisfação (não no sentido da mera realização das expectativas sobre as opções de interface, mas da superação delas de maneiras únicas e interessantes).

### Concluindo

O planejamento de uma interface em geral segue esses três critérios, pois existe uma certa hierarquia de importância entre eles para que um produto seja realmente efetivo em produzir uma boa experiência de uso, algo comparável* à [hierarquia de necessidades humanas de Maslow](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Maslow):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>*Patrick W. Jordan. Designing Pleasurable Products. Taylor & Francis, 2002</sup>

Produtos utilitários (como um martelo, por exemplo) precisam ser antes de tudo funcionais (serem úteis pra algo). Só então atributos como eficácia e eficiência tornam-se relevantes para o utilizador. Por fim, atributos menos pragmáticos (comumente chamados de hedônicos ou afetivos), como apelo, estética, etc, podem então se tornar relevantes e permitir que a satisfação seja algo além da mera ausência de desconforto (ergonomia) e que os utilizadores criem significado para o produto ("o meu martelo funciona igual ao seu, mas é bem mais legal").

Acontece que por mais que essa hierarquia exista, as fronteiras entre elas são bastante nebulosas dependendo do tipo de produto intencionado. Nem todo produto tem caráter principalmente utilitário, e isso vale também para sistemas computacionais. Jogos digitais, por exemplo, não têm requisitos a serem atendidos, então o caráter hedônico/afetivo torna-se mais importante. Isso não quer dizer, porém, que atributos de usabilidade não sejam necessários para esse tipo de produto. Afinal, mesmo que os "problemas" em jogos digitais sejam intencionalmente projetados para **não serem** fáceis, os jogadores ainda precisam ser capazes de entender a interface e saber/lembrar como utilizá-la de forma eficaz e eficiente. De fato, alguns autores** indicam que esses atributos têm suas relevâncias alteradas conforme um eixo utilitário (que indica se a aplicação é mais de "escritório" ou de "entretenimento"):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>**Bentley, Johnston e Von Baggo. Putting Some Emotion into Requirements Engineering. Proceedings of the 7th Australian Workshop on Requirements Engineering, Deakin University, 2002</sup>

De todas as formas, faz parte do "planejamento" a avaliação dos conceitos de projeto, utilizando protótipos de fidelidade crescente e com participantes representativos dos usuários reais do sistema. Pois, só assim é possível validar que a função atende a necessidade e que a interação é a mais usável possível, além de ganhar indicações valiosíssimas sobre as escolhas de design que mais carregam potencial afetivo para os utilizadores.

Para saber mais sobre a construção de protótipos, [eu sugiro ler este material muito bacana](http://thiagonasc.com/desenvolvimento-web/a-importancia-dos-prototipos-no-desenvolvimento-de-sistemas). Além disso, aqui mesmo no SOPT há bastante informação útil sobre o assunto nas tags [ux](/questions/tagged/ux) e [usabilidade](/questions/tagged/usabilidade).

Answer (score 7):

Nem vou tentar adicionar nada ao que o Luiz Vieira disse porque ele entende muito mais do assunto que eu. Vou apenas complementar um ponto importante para qualquer interface e que para web fica ainda mais importante.

Sempre que se projeta uma interface deve-se levar em consideração quem vai usar a aplicação. Por quem entenda também o que a pessoa vai fazer, como, quando, onde e porque ela vai usar a interface.

E um dos pontos específicos mais importantes é entender que ela será usada em situações diferentes (trabalho, diversão, por gosto ou obrigação) com diferentes experiências prévias de uso de tecnologia e da própria web, em locais mais ou menos apropriados, e principalmente em dispositivos diferentes com tamanhos de telas diferentes, com entrada de dados diferentes (mouse, toque, teclado físico ou virtual) em sistemas operacionais diferentes com fontes disponíveis diferentes, com navegadores versões diferentes e com capacidades limitadas ou modernas e ainda com configurações diferentes, incluindo aí o JavaScript desabilitado.

Um dos erros mais comuns na web é achar que todo mundo terá as condições que o desenvolvedor tem para usar a mesma interface. É comum não se preocupar com técnicas de [*graceful degradation ou progressive-enhancement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101).

Outro erro é achar que o tal do *layout* responsivo é solução para tudo. Pode ser, mas muitas vezes a experiência fica prejudicada. Tenha isto em mente. Tem que analisar o custo e o benefício de fazer *layouts* específicos.

Pode parecer que estou dizendo que se é para web deve funcionar em qualquer situação. E este é outro erro, você pode abrir mão de alguns usuários em função do custo. Planejar é pensar em tudo, não em resolver tudo.

E tome cuidado para achar que alguém tem capacidade de entender alguma coisa. Quantos "desenvolvedores" chegaram aqui e não conseguiram usar as ferramentas de formatação mesmo depois de algumas tentativas e muitos desistiram. Imagine nos outros *sites* da rede onde pode não ter desenvolvedores.

Outro ponto importante que causa problemas é querer ser artista na interface. Já vi inúmeras vezes *designers* querem mostrar como são criativos e fazerem um *website* se tornar um enigma para usar.

Já se pensava na padronização de interface nos tempo da programação para console. Não dava para inventar muito e as pessoas usavam bem poucas aplicações. Mesmo assim foi criado um [padrão para que todas as aplicações](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) se parecessem, que funcionasse sempre da mesma forma para não ter que reaprender e se adaptar em cada nova aplicação.

Com o advento da GUI e a proliferação de aplicações além da ampliação do público usuário uma padronização se tornou ainda mais necessária. Já no tempo do console era comum os programadores quererem ser criativos, com GUI dava para ser mais ainda e até hoje vemos softwares que são aberrações. Muitos desenvolvedores não tem noção do mal que estão causando. Eles acham que fazer mais bonito (o que frequentemente é o oposto do resultado real obtido) os torna melhor do que são. E pior é que algumas pessoas acabam dando valor para isto.

Fazer bonito costuma ser o mesmo que inventar uma notação desconhecida pelos usuários. E na web todo mundo quer que seu *website* seja especial e por isto tentam deixar ele mais bonito (nada errado em ser bonito) só que em termos de usabilidade ele fica especial no mal sentido.

Imagine para web onde o computador entrou na vida de praticamente todo mundo e que cada *website* é uma nova aplicação que a pessoa tem que aprender usar. Você quer ser criativo ou quer facilitar a vida de quem está acessando? Respeite o tempo das pessoas, faça elas se sentirem à vontade em uma página que ela nunca visitou antes.

Se as pessoas já erram muito em aplicações mais específicas elas erram mais para web que são mais abrangentes. Planejar uma interface já é meio caminho andado. Pensar nos pontos específicos da web ajuda andar o resto.

A web é mais complexa do que as pessoas imaginam e talvez por isto frequentemente os desenvolvedores pressupõem algumas coisas equivocadamente.

E lembre-se que funcionalidade/conteúdo é mais importante que tudo. Claro que usabilidade e experiência ruim pode matar um *site* muito funcional, mas usar bem algo vazio não é do interesse de ninguém.

Então você tem que ler muito sobre o assunto para conseguir planejar de forma minimamente adequada. Precisa entender cada ponto, precisa questionar cada decisão que for tomar quando está projetando a interface.

Além dos *links* que o Luiz passou ainda aconselho acompanhar e perguntar sempre que tiver dúvidas específicas (obviamente fazendo *cross post* aqui :P) no [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Alguns HIGs disponíveis que ajudam dar uma ideia do que pode ser necessário para seu planejamento:

- [Guia de usabilidade do governo americano](http://guidelines.usability.gov/).
- [SAP](http://www.sapdesignguild.org/resources/web_guidelines/index.htm).
- [Livro WebStyle Guide](http://www.webstyleguide.com/wsg3/index.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).