# UI e desenvolvimento desktop .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wpf, gui

Estou no começo do desenvolvimento de uma aplicação comercial em C#, porém, tenho minhas dúvidas de como irei fazer a parte visual do aplicativo (UI).

Já trabalhei com Windows Forms e WPF. 
No evento Build da Microsoft, em 2014, foi dito que o Windows Forms já não recebe mais novas *features*, somente correções de bugs, o que me preocupa um pouco. 
Os contras do WPF é a performance na hora de desenvolver. Em projetos grandes, o WPF não é a melhor opção. O editor do XAML no Visual Studio trava demais! Já tentei em várias configurações e várias versões diferentes do VS, ele não tem desempenho da hora de desenvolver em projetos grandes.
O UWP também não seria uma boa opção pra mim, se não estou enganado, só funciona no Windows 8 ou superior, com  a introdução do Metro. (corrijam-me se estou errado!)

Não tenho problemas em aprender uma nova tecnologia, tenho bastante tempo.

**Algumas referências:**

- [Superuser, 'Visual Studio Performance problems when writing XAML', em 17/08/13](https://superuser.com/questions/632918/visual-studio-performance-problems-when-writing-xaml)
- [Visual Studio User Voice, 'Improve the XAML Designer performance', em 25/08/11](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2204137-improve-the-xaml-designer-performance)
- [MSDN Social, 'When Microsoft will stop to offer support for Windows Forms?' em 25/06/2008](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c4277a4e-9146-4dae-9eaa-773ef2802fe2/when-microsoft-will-stop-to-offer-support-for-windows-forms?forum=winforms)
- [Code Project, 'Is WPF dead: the present and future of WPF', em 12/09/2014](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/818281/is-wpf-dead-the-present-and-future-of-wpf)

---

Quais são as tecnologias mais [recomendadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45795/41056) para criar a interface do usuário que posso usar com o C# + Visual Studio em minhas condições?

Comment: Parece que já pesquisou bem e sabe tudo o que precisa objetivamente. O que mais poderia ser dito além de opiniões das pessoas qual cada um gosta mais?

Comment: @bigown não opiniões, preciso de alternativas!!

Comment: As viáveis são essas que você postou.

Comment: @bigown Só? Nenhuma parece atender meus requisitos.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao maravilhoso mundo do desktop onde nenhuma solução é adequada :D A única alternativa que extra que alguém usa é o GTK#, mas no Linux, porque não tem nada melhor. No Windows ele é a pior escolha sempre.

Comment: @bigown triste!