# Muitas telas ou uma tela com muitas informações?

Tags: ux, aplicação-desktop, aplicação-web, usabilidade

Eu vejo uma tendência cada vez maior, embora isto já existisse antes, de criar várias telas, vários passos para executar uma única ação.

Claro que o advento de telas menores incentiva isto. Mas estou falando de desktop normal. O mesmo vale para aplicações web "normais" (que não são feitas para rodar em *mobile*).

Também entendo que [telas superpopuladas de informação](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVWub.gif), que permitem fazer várias coisas, muitas vezes não relacionadas, não fazem sentido. Mas percebo que antes o que você fazia em um *click*, em interfaces modernizadas acabam exigindo dois, três ou mais clicks para se alcançar o mesmo propósito. Muitas vezes você limpa a tela mas dificulta o acesso à operação desejada.

Este tipo de filosofia, me parece, prejudica a descoberta da operação.

Realmente atrapalha ter muita informação? Por que?

Existem estudos ou pelo menos informações consistentes que mostram que um realmente é melhor que outro? Por que esconder operações é melhor? E se não é, por que estão adotando isto? Seria interessante ver um comparação entre as duas situações para entender as vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma, e com isto ajudar a entender quando e optar por um mais que o outro.

Existe alguma forma de facilitar a descoberta, facilitar o acesso às operações, sem "sujar" a tela? Há exceções onde não devemos aplicar uma destas filosofias?

Comment: Teria um exemplo, de cada uma das duas situação? Para podermos compreender melhor as "filosofias" que você está citando. E suas reais diferenças, dificuldades e operações "escondidas".

Comment: Estou tentando achar um antes ou depois para postar, se achar algo legal, eu edito. que mostre bem isto. Mas falo em termos gerais. Só para não deixar sem nenhum exemplo: para chegar em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve precisa de 4 cliques. Antes precisa de menos. Outro exemplo é o uso de abas ao invés de divisões na tela. Eu vejo aplicações que chegam ao ponto de exigir ficar trocando de tela para comparar as informações. Apesar de entender que isto tem a ver com o mobile, o Windows 8 elevou isto: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/ O Gmail é um bom exemplo como mudou.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### TL;DR

**Realmente atrapalha ter muita informação? Por que?**

Em teoria sim. Porque a capacidade da atenção humana é limitada. O usuário pode não perceber o que deveria, e mesmo que o faça isso pode gerar esforço cognitivo demasiado para uma interação mais continuada.

**Existem estudos ou pelo menos informações consistentes que mostram que um realmente é melhor que outro?**

Existem inúmeros. Mas os estudos mais gerais servem como abordagem padrão. O melhor estudo para você vai ser aquele que você fizer com os seus usuários usando protótipos do produto que prepara para eles.

**Por que esconder operações é melhor? E se não é por que estão adotando isto?**

Pode ser melhor esconder porque facilita a interação local do usuário (ele não precisa se preocupar com o que não é importante no contexto atual). Porém, o usuário jamais deveria precisar se lembrar de muita informação. Novamente, a capacidade humana é limitada.

**Existe alguma forma de facilitar a descoberta, facilitar o acesso às operações sem "sujar" a tela?**

Existem inúmeras, todas usando algum dos sentidos humanos (afinal, o usuário precisa ser capaz de perceber a informação passada). Jogos, por exemplo, fazem uso metódico - e condizente com a fantasia (leia-se, conhecimento prévio do usuário) - de sons. O exemplo clássico é o som de espadas se chocando no Age of Empires, que indica que uma batalha se inicia fora da tela do usuário. Aplicativos móveis também vibram o dispositivo. Enfim, você não precisa necessariamente usar a tela para passar alguma informação.

**Há exceções onde não devemos aplicar uma destas filosofias?**

Certamente há. A mais óbvia é a construção de aplicativos para cegos. Nesse caso não importa a quantidade, a tela não é a melhor forma de transmitir as informações. Pode parecer um exemplo extremo, mas a ideia é que essas exceções decorrem da sua própria análise dos seus usuários, com as preferências, expectativas e necessidades deles.

### Versão original e mais completa

Há duas coisas que são muito importantes de serem consideradas no projeto de interação com um produto: apelo e engajamento.

O apelo está diretamente relacionado às preferências do utilizador e às questões estéticas do produto, como o quão agradável, belo e *curioso* ele parece. Trata-se de um primeiro nível da interação, em que o utilizador escolhe começar a utilizar o produto. Já o engajamento, embora também inclua atributos de preferência e estética, tem uma relação mais forte com a satisfação na experiência de uso. Trata-se de um contato mais contínuo, em que o usuário escolhe continuar interagindo com o produto. Se as expectativas criadas no primeiro contato com o produto são satisfeitas ou superadas de forma positiva na continuidade do contato, geralmente têm-se o engajamento.

### Apelo, Quantidade de Informação e Esforço Cognitivo

O apelo está intimamente ligado à curiosidade, que é uma necessidade humana básica de entender o mundo. Essa necessidade advém de e conduz a interação. Nós humanos interagimos com o mundo não apenas alterando-o por meio de nossas ações, mas também percebendo as mudanças que nós mesmos e outros agentes fazem nele. Acontece que o mecanismo de atenção (que filtra a enorme quantidade de dados sensoriais que continuamente recebemos do mundo e decide o que é relavante ou não de acordo com as nossas intenções) é limitado. Estima-se<sup>*</sup> que cada pessoa pode processar 126 bits de informação por segundo, o que significa que somos capazes de prestar atenção a um máximo *teórico* de três conversas simultâneas (isso se conseguirmos ignorar completamente todo o resto, como as percepções internas do nosso próprio organismo).

<sub>* A fonte dessa informação é o trabalho do psicólogo [Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihaly_Csikszentmihalyi), no livro [*Flow: The Psychology of Optimal Experience*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061339202). Quem desejar ler sobre o assunto de interação, atenção e motivação, de forma (talvez) um pouco mais facilitada, pode ler [este meu artigo sobre diversão](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268035628_Understanding_Fun).</sub>

> Se você não acredita nesta limitação da atenção, [faça o teste e tente contar o
>   número de passes do time branco neste famoso vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahg6qcgoay4). :)

É por isso que a evolução fez o cérebro se interessar tanto em padrões levemente desconhecidos. Ao observar algo que não tem novidade alguma, esse algo é simplesmente desinteressante (já conhecemos o assunto, não nos interessa pois não vai ajudar o organismo a se sair melhor nas ações com o mundo). Porém, por outro lado, se esse algo é completamente desconhecido e incapaz de ser ao menos comparado a outra coisa que se conhece, ele é caótico e consequentemente também desinteressante. Por isso que uma tela de TV só com estática, que tem muitíssima informação do ponto de vista da Teoria da Informação, é simplesmente chata e não causa sequer um início de apelo. Mas é por isso também que puzzles muito difíceis, por mais apelativos que sejam inicialmente, dificultam o engajamento porque os usuários simplesmente não conseguem saber como prosseguir.

Todo esse bla-bla-bla teórico é pra demonstrar que há um ponto ideal na quantidade de informações a ser exibida. Ela deve ser suficiente para causar apelo e excitar a curiosidade (e não pense só em jogos; um alarme em um sistema de controle de fábrica precisa ser capaz de atrair a atenção rapidamente!), mas não pode exceder as limitações naturais dos seres humanos a ponto de causar desconforto e assim dificultar o engajamento. Mesmo que muita informação seja compreendida e cause apelo, ela pode requerer muito esforço cognitivo e assim simplesmente cansar o usuário. É por isso que lá nos [Princípios de Usabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27099/o-que-s%C3%A3o-princ%C3%ADpios-de-usabilidade) prega-se, entre outras coisas, evitar que o usuário tenha de se lembrar do caminho nos menus para um comando, por exemplo.

Note, entretanto, que a mera existência de muita informação nem sempre é ruim. Ruim é alagar o usuário com toda ela de uma vez só, tornando-o incapaz de extrair algo de útil dela. O resultado de uma pesquisa no Google, por exemplo, tem muitísima informação, mas ela está espalhada ao longo de páginas facilmente navegáveis. E, principalmente, é muito claro ao usuário que existe essa possibilidade (ele percebe que há mais dados além dos que está enxergando atualmente). De fato, aqui há a ligação com o esforço físico do próximo tópico: o usuário pode não se importar tanto em ter de navegar para o próximo item muitas vezes, contanto que essa ação de navegar seja relevante e simples.

O exemplo que você usou na pergunta (a interface cheia de campos) é intrinsicamente pior porque o usuário não sabe o que fazer a seguir do que pelo fato de ele ter disponível toda aquela quantidade de informação. Este fantástico artigo, chamado [Desmystifying UX Design](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2012/10/demystifying-ux-design-common-false-beliefs-and-their-remedies-part-1.php), tem muito mais informações relevantes a esse respeito.

### Engajamento e Esforço Ergonômico

O esforço ergonômico, ou de uso (como o número de cliques), é mais relevante no engajamento do que no apelo. Isso é natural, pois durante o primeiro contato o usuário ainda não usou o produto propriamente e só tem expectativas a respeito de como será interagir com ele. O esforço cognitivo, tratado no tópico anterior, já é iniciado a partir do primeiro contato, quando o usuário procura entender como funciona o produto.

É uma tendência acreditar que muito esforço físico prejudica o engajamento porque faz o usuário simplesmente cansar de interagir com o produto. Por exemplo, o jogo de luta de boxe do Nintendo Wii pode parecer muitíssimo interessante em um primeiro contato (tem grande apelo), mas após algumas partidas o cansaço físico de ter de socar o ar continuamente pode tornar a experiência menos satisfatória do que se imaginava. Ainda assim isso *não é* uma verdade universal, pois tudo depende das preferências e das expectativas que são criadas nos usuários durante o apelo. Há usuários que têm imensa satisfação em dispender esforço físico, e certamente irão perceber que esse é o tipo de jogo pra eles a partir das primeiras interações.

Em outras palavras, não é o esforço em si que prejudica o engajamento, e sim a percepção de sua relevância por parte dos usuários. No artigo que eu citei anteriormente sobre a desmistificação da UX, há o exemplo do maior número de cliques em uma interface de Assistente (Wizard), mas que é percebido como facilitador pelos usuários porque não requerem grande esforço físico ou cognitivo individualmente, não sobrecarregam o usuário com perguntas, e permitem que ele atinja o objetivo de forma gradual.

Eu infelizmente não tenho mais a referência desse estudo, mas o mecanismo de subir o vidro elétrico dos carros com apenas um toque veio de testes de empresas automotoras japonesas com seus usuários, em que se observou justamente esse fato. Nas primeiras versões, os usuários eram requeridos a continuar apertando o botão para que o vidro subisse ou descesse. Por mais rápido que o vidro subisse, os usuários sempre reclamavam que o mecanismo era lento demais (mesmo que fosse muito mais rápido do que girar uma manivela, como era feito até então). Acontece que continuar pressionando o botão significa realizar esforço físico, mesmo que bem menor do que girar a manivela. Mas a percepção do resultado por aquele esforço era muito pequena, comparativamente. Enquanto se estava segurando o botão - uma tarefa tão simples a ponto de ser ridícula - o tempo parecia passar mais devagar porque a sensação de ociosidade (*idleness*) era enorme. Por isso os japoneses criaram o subir/descer automático a partir de um toque. :)

Aliás, [há estudos](https://pages.shanti.virginia.edu/Benjamin_A_Converse/files/2012/02/Sackett-et-al-2010-Psych-Sci-_-Time-Flies1.pdf) que também observaram esse fenômeno da relação da ação com o tempo. Após intencionalmente distorcer a percepção de tempo ("enganando" os participantes com relógios que passam mais rapidamente), comprovou-se que mesmo tarefas consideradas muito chatas (como contar palitos de fósforo!) são experienciadas como mais prazeirosas por causa dessa percepção de tempo voando...

### E como Planejar a Interação

A melhor forma, segundo todas as fontes de UX que eu já estudei e a minha própria experiência, é a avaliação da interação diretamente com os usuários, principalmente usando protótipos de baixa fidelidade (como construídos em papel). A baixa fidelidade do protótipo facilita a construção (em termos de custo e tempo) e evita que o projetista tenha apego ao produto criado (*essa interface ficou tão bonitinha e o usuário não gostou... ah, ele é que não sabe o que quer... my precious!*). Além disso, a avaliação permite observar os pontos críticos em todos os aspectos discutidos anteriormente. Sobre esse assunto, eu sugiro também ler esta outra pergunta sobre [o que são Wireframes, Mockups e Protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21677/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-wireframe-prot%C3%B3tipo-e-mockup) e o livro *[Interaction Design: Beyond Human-Computer Interaction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470665769)*.

Comment: Quem imaginaria que logo você iria dar uma resposta deste nível sobre este assunto? :D

Comment: +1 Se alguém vir um TL;DR no inicio dessa resposta e pular o resto... **volte lá e continue lendo até o final pois vale a pena!**

Answer (score 13):

Bom, no seu caso a pergunta pode mudar com o decorrer do tempo. Pois a de 3 à 5 anos atrás as interfaces de hoje não seriam possíveis.

Não existe uma convenção da "melhor forma de trabalhar" com design de interfaces, até por que, cada projeto possui requisitos diferentes.

Ao desenvolver uma interface deve ser levado em conta alguns critérios, como:

**Clareza**
Clareza, segundo [Kevin Matz](http://architectingusability.com/2011/05/26/using-the-gestalt-laws-of-perception-in-ui-design/), é um dos principais objetivos ao desenvolver uma interface. Pois o intuito é elaborar uma interface onde o usuário consiga interagir e entender como ela funciona. 
Claro que a "quantidade de clicks" deve ser levado em conta, porém não deve-se superar a clareza e a utilidade de sua interface.

**Atenção**
Vivemos com vários fatores que tiram nossa atenção, ao decorrer do dia. Sua interface deve ser capaz de lidar com fatores externos.
Não coloque em sua "tela", informações que podem tirar a atenção do usuário. Sua aplicação deverá ser capaz de lidar com esse fator.

**Objetivo**
Adicionar em uma tela várias funcionalidades por deixar "mais fácil", acaba prejudicando 
a interação do usuário com a sua aplicação. Pois em meio a muitas funcionalidades, ele acaba se "perdendo", dificultando o acesso. 
Cada tela deve ser focada em um objetivo final, deixando assim o método de aprendizado e memorização por parte do usuário mais fácil. Afinal, quando desenvolvemos uma aplicação, seja ela Desktop, Web ou Mobile, ela será utilizada por N tipos de usuários, cada um com sua forma de aprendizado.

**Outras Operações**
Quando for necessário adicionar "Operações Secundárias" em sua tela, certifique que o usuário saiba que esta é uma Operação Secundária, que ela está ali apenas como complemento, e não para ser a atenção principal.
**Exemplo:** Uma opção para compartilhar uma foto no facebook, está ali apenas como complemento. O objetivo principal é que as pessoas possam ver e interagir com a foto, compartilhar a mesma se torna uma fator secundário.

Respondendo a sua pergunta diretamente, tendo em vista que deixar um número maior de telas, deixará sua aplicação "mais fácil" de se interagir, não há problemas, pelo contrário. O intuito de uma "[Interface Amigável](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=interface%20amig%C3%A1vel)" é elaborar uma forma de interação, onde o usuário não sinta dificuldades ao interagir com sua aplicação.

**Resumindo:** Não leve em conta a "quantidade de telas ou botões", e sim "a forma de interação com o usuário", pois isso que irá definir se sua interface está clara ou não.

Deixarei algumas fontes, ligadas diretamente e indiretamente com sua dúvida:
Gestalt - Indiretamente ligado a sua dúvida.
[Gestalt Interface Design](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gestalt%20interface%20design)
[User Interface](http://conferences.computer.org/stc/2014/papers/5034a062.pdf)
[UI Design](http://architectingusability.com/2011/05/26/using-the-gestalt-laws-of-perception-in-ui-design/) 

[The Future of UI](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-future-of-user-interfaces--webdesign-13246)
[Avaliação de Interfaces de Usuário – Conceitos e
Métodos](http://www.urisan.tche.br/~paludo/material/IHM/Material/avaliacao.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

## Primeiro uma introdução

### Relação Aplicação x Usuário

Existe entre aplicação e usuário uma relação que
quando duradoura modela a ambos.

**Primeiro contato**

Quando a relação se estabelece, ou seja, quando o
usuário tem o primeiro contato com a aplicação,
o que acontece é que o usuário vai gostar ou não
daquilo baseado em seus gostos pessoais... que na
minha opinião está intimamente relacionado às
experiências passadas.

Se o usuário está acostumado com interfaces limpas,
ou interfaces mais populadas, ou interfaces de linha
de comando, ou GUI's ele vai imediatamente ter uma
impressão baseada nas experiências passadas.

**Mas o que isso tem há ver?**

Para mim, não existem interfaces boas ou ruins.
O que existe para mim são:

- interfaces que seguem padrões estabelecidos,
- ou tentam criar o seu próprio padrão.

O primeiro caso, vai com certeza causar um
impacto muito menor nos usuários, e vai se adequar
às experiencias de uma gama maior de usuários.

O segundo caso, vai ter mais dificuldade em
conquistar usuários, exatamente pelo fato, de as
coisas não estarem onde elas esperam que estejam.

**Moldagem bidirecional com o tempo**

Com o passar do tempo, a aplicação, tanto como os
utilizadores vão mudando e um vai moldando o outro.
Se a aplicação muda, e desagrada alguém, é possível
que esse usuário migre para um concorrente.
Se muitos usuários pedem dada alteração, então
uma fabricante de software provavelmente às ouvirá,
assim moldando o software.

Assim sendo as interfaces mudam, seguindo
indicadores de tendências, baseadas nos usuários,
e seus objetivos.

Agora tenta mudar algo que está culturalmente
entranhado, igual ao botão Iniciar no Windows.
Ou então deixar a interface totalmente sem nada
igual o que queriam fazer com o Microsoft Office.

Ou seja, existe uma questão da experiência passada
até entre versões do mesmo software.

### Relação Aplicação x Objetivo

Uma organização específica de uma aplicação qualquer,
além de estar relacionada com as experiências do
usuário, também está relacionada ao objetivo dela
(quanta novidade!).

Só que isso possui implicações, sobre os questionamentos,
afinal uma interface mais populada dá agilidade para o
usuário treinado, enquanto uma interface mais limpinha
dá uma interface menos assustadora para os usuários
ocasionais, fuçadores e a massa em geral.

## Respostas:

### Realmente atrapalha ter muita informação? Por que?

Me embasando no que disse anteriormente, para mim,
a resposta é **nenhum tipo de organização atrapalha,
caso o usuário já esteja acostumado, e também o uso
da aplicação corresponda ao objetivo**

### Existem estudos ou pelo menos informações consistentes que mostram que um realmente é melhor que outro?

Certamente... mas eu vou dar uma de Sócrates, e
tentar responder usando somente o plano das idéias,
com argumentos meus.

Se for realmente muito importante posso procurar alguns.
Geralmente são estudos relacionados aos termos UX.
Já vi estudos até sobre a posição que os labels devem
ficar em relação às caixas onde se entra com os dados...
só não me lembro onde.

### Por que esconder operações é melhor?

Não acho que seja melhor... para mim, é uma estratégia de
marketing, você atinge as massas pois não assusta o fuçador,
o explorador. E também não limita o cara que
vai se aprofundar na aplicação, a pesar de este cara
ser prejudicado na agilidade.

### E se não é por que estão adotando isto?

Pois o mercado para utilizadores que requerem agilidade
é menor. Não quer dizer que não exista. Imagine um software
para monitorar um reator nuclear... tem que estar tudo
a um dedo de distância... a um olhar de distância.

### Existe alguma forma de facilitar a descoberta, facilitar o acesso às operações sem "sujar" a tela?

Acho que sim.

No futuro talvez só de pensar em algo, já aconteça...
mas atendo ao presente, acho que o legal seria juntar o
melhor dos dois mundos:

1. a aplicação vem de fábrica muito limpa
2. ela seria customizável para que o usuário monte o seu próprio painel de controle, mega-powerful
3. se a organização (empresa) desejar, deve haver uma forma de forçar um layout,
   para então treinar os funcionários naquele layout
4. poderia haver uma forma de compartilhar um layout customizado, globalmente,
   criando assim um padrão global para utilizadores de uma certa aplicação,
   endossados ou não pelo criador da aplicação

### Há exceções onde não devemos aplicar uma destas filosofias?

Com certeza.

Depende do requisito de grau de agilidade necessário para os utilizadores.
Depende do requisito estético do cliente específico.
Há tantos requisitos que podem limitar a interface.

## Epílogo

Isso aqui é a minha opinião... como desenvolvedor, utilizador,
pensador... Minhas experiências passadas certamente influenciaram
este texto. Então com certeza, isso tudo é menos que uma fração
pequena das possibilidades.

Comment: Muito boa resposta. Realmente, faltou alguma indicação de fontes, mas a sua abordagem socrática tá no caminho certo. :)

Answer (score 7):

Ter muita informação a priori não atrapalha nem ajuda.
Depende de quem é o foco da sua aplicação.

Se você utilizar o Princípio de Pareto/Princípio 80-20 (que está na base do conceito da Cauda Longa), pode entender que 80% dos visitantes vão utilizar 20% das funcionalidades/informações e 20% dos visitantes vão utilizar 80% das funcionalidades/informações. Ou seja, disponibilizar mais funcionalidades/informações vai garantir uma forma mais refinada para um público menor, porém especializado, mas é possível que afaste aqueles menos especializados, menos íntimos do conteúdo. Ao passo que menos informações vai garantir um maior entendimento por um público maior mas pode frustar os mais especializados.

Acho que a discussão tem relação com o texto Getting Real, da ex-37Signal, atual Basecamp. http://gettingreal.37signals.com/GR_por.php#ch01

Eles são muito radicais neste ponto.
Resumidamente, eles colocam da seguinte forma:

- Getting Real é o menor, mais rápido e melhor caminho para construir
  software.
- Getting Real é menos. Menos massa, menos software, menos
  funcionalidades, menos papéis, menos tudo que não é essencial (e a
  maioria do que você pensa ser essencial realmente não é).
- Getting Real é permanecer pequeno e ser ágil.
- Getting Real é sobre iterações e baixar os custos da mudança.
- Getting Real tem tudo a ver com lançamento, refinamento e melhorar
  constantemente, o que o torna o caminho perfeito para software
  baseado em web.

Com a febre dos One-page Sites, é muito comum ver criadores na tentativa de encaixar seu conteúdo neste modelo sem, ao menos, avaliar se esta solução é a melhor para seu objetivo.

De fato pode ser mais simples colocar todas as informações em uma única página para contar uma história, por exemplo. Rolar a tela é muito mais prático e intuitivo que clicar em 4 ou 5 botões e visitar todo o conteúdo. Mas dependendo do tamanho do conteúdo e dos desdobramentos, o ideal é ter multiplas telas.

No cadastro em uma loja online, por exemplo. Talvez o mais simples seja dividir a finalização da compra em multiplas telas ao invés de disponibilizar uma única e grande página com tudo.

Não há uma resposta única para a pergunta, o ideal é pensar simples, monitorar e aumentar a complexidade da aplicação sob demanda adquirida no monitoramento — usar a estatística que diferencia este meio de outros não digitais. Quando digo mais simples, é pensando neste usuário padrão, por vezes for dummies mesmo, e isso não significa que o projeto não seja bom, certo?

Comment: Eu acho que você focou a sua resposta no caráter funcional da aplicação (oferecer menos ou mais funções). Porém, a questão é mais no sentido do acesso às funções (sejam elas em quaisquer quantidades), por meio da UI. A referência que você passou é interessante, mas principalmente nesse item que você não citou: "*Caindo na Real inicia com a construção da interface, ou seja, as telas reais que as pessoas irão utilizar. Começa com as experiências reais dos clientes, construindo a partir disso para trás.*" Ou seja, começa a partir da prototipação da UI para avaliar a interação dos usuários. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Tem razão sobre o foco da resposta, mas o mesmo raciocínio não se aplica ao que está na pergunta? Avaliar objetivamente o uso (seja em protótipo ou em "beta eterno") é uma boa maneira de decidir o que ocultar, ou remover, dependendo do caso. Deixando de lado os modismos de sair escondendo tudo, tem muito "depende" envolvido. Quando na sua resposta você fala em "ponto ideal", entendo que ele varie em função do que a aplicação faz, e do público-alvo, certo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não estou seguro de que se aplique exatamente o mesmo raciocínio. Veja, por exemplo, essa passagem da resposta: "Ou seja, disponibilizar mais funcionalidades/informações vai garantir uma forma mais refinada para um público menor, porém especializado [...]". O que é um público especializado? E isso não é necessariamente verdade. Talvez o AR esteja imaginando um usuário especialista em Bash no Unix, por exemplo, que já conhece muitos dos comandos existentes. Mas o fato é que a interface que ele usa é simples, e **não tem** todos os comandos disponíveis ali, exibidos todo o tempo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Além do mais, muito embora um protótipo possa ser utilizado para entender a necessidade do cliente, não faz sentido esconder alguma função que o usuário nunca irá utilizar. Se é algo desnecessário, nem deveria ser implementado (quanto mais exibido/escondido). Por isso me parece que o foco da pergunta é mais no sentido da experiência e da usabilidade com as funções necessárias/existentes. De todas as formas, eu acho que essa resposta é bacana no sentido de que auxilia também com esse tipo de discussão que estamos tendo. :)

Answer (score 2):

Desculpem o meu pragmatismo mas, depois de ler as resposta existente até ao momento e de ler alguns artigos sobre o assunto, a minha resposta só pode ser:

Ponham-se na *"pele do utilizador"* quando forem desenvolver/idealizar qualquer UI.

<sup>**Nota:** Não me penalizem por postar isto como resposta e não como comentário.</sup>

Comment: A resposta faz sentido, não achei ela ruim não, mas acho que salvaria ela se coloque um pouco mais o que isto significa. Por exemplo, minha pergunta ocorreu porque eu não gosto de ficar dando vários clicks p/ chegar onde eu quero. Não tenho certeza se isto é o que outras pessoas pensam.

Comment: É isso ai. :) Dica de onde continuar a fundamentação da sua resposta: [User-Centered Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-centered_design). "*The chief difference from other product design philosophies is that user-centered design tries to optimize the product around how users can, want, or need to use the product, rather than forcing the users to change their behavior to accommodate the product.*"

Comment: *"não gosto de ficar dando vários clicks p/ chegar onde eu quero."* refere-se a situações em particular ou é sempre assim?. Nessa altura você pensou: *"Eu faria isto diferente?"*. É uma questão de opinião. Este é um assunto amplamente estudado mas os resultados tem de ser vistos apenas como princípios a ter em conta e não como verdades absolutas. Na minha opinião aqui deve imperar o bom senso, um equilíbrio entre quantidade de informação/relação entre ela e usabilidade. Pôr-me na "pele do utilizador" é a regra que eu sigo primeiro, o *feedback* recebido é o que irá *"afinar"* a solução.

Comment: @LuizVieira, Vou ler.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que varia muito de aplicação para aplicação. Ao meu ver, temos que aplicativos com muita informação podem ser úteis para quem precisa de mais agilidade no processo e busca descobrir tudo que precisa em menor tempo. Porém, uma tela "pesada" para alguns usuários pode fazer com que a sua aplicação seja uma experiência cansativa e que não atenda muito ao objetivo dos mesmos (já que muitas pessoas têm preguiça de procurar as coisas).

A escolha entre uma tela com muita informação ou com pouca informação e mais telas, deve ser cuidadosamente analisada de acordo com o objetivo do software e o público alvo.

Comment: Você poderia fundamentar isto? Ou é apenas a sua opinião? Note que existem perguntas específicas que escrevi. Elas não precisam ser respondidas diretamente mas precisa ter informações que ajudem informar alguma coisa, pelo menos ajudar tomar uma decisão. A sua resposta diz para fazer justamente o que eu estou perguntando. Como analisar cuidadosamente? Quais critérios usar?

Comment: Foi apenas minha opinião mesmo, mas vou buscar procurar algumas fontes para  fundamentar melhor. Achei interessante a discussão :)

Answer (score 1):

O livro `Designing Web Interfaces` da Editora O'Reilly (focado somente em padrões de interface e em algumas "convenções" que visam fornecer uma melhor experiencia de usuário) "diz" que devemos limitar a quantidade de informações escondendo-a ou postergando sua aparição ao usuario (pois a grande quantidade de conteudo (seja em um form de cadastro ou de noticias) pode incomodar, desmotivar e até afugentar o usuário) para isso é mostrado o uso de alguns padrões visuais alguns citados abaixo:

- Accordion: que limita a quantidade de conteúdo e opções visíveis ao usuário.
- Dialog overlay: que foca a visão/concentração do usuário em um conteúdo especifio (pode ser uma informação relevante ou um formulário).
- Detail Overlay: que mostra os detalhes de certo elemento quando o mesmo é focado pelo mouse.