# O que é UX (User Experience)?

Tags: terminologia, ux

Vejo algumas perguntas no site com a tag UX sobre posicionamento de controles, cores, etc. Isso normalmente me parece fazer parte das escolhas do *designer* (ou até mesmo do usuário).

O que é UX? E como isso pode me ajudar a desenvolver aplicações melhores ou mais agradáveis para os usuários?

Comment: Olá! Eu também estava estudando sobre o assunto e encontrei este ótimo vídeo: https://youtu.be/-L4gEk7cOfk, vai te ajudar bastante a entender mais sobre UX.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que são princípios de Usabilidade?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27099/70)

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais são as diferenças entre Wireframe, Protótipo e Mockup?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21677/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-wireframe-prot%c3%b3tipo-e-mockup)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

UX é uma sigla que significa "Experiência do Usuário" (*User Experience*, no original em inglês). Ela se refere a um campo de estudo dentro da Interação Humano-Computador (IHC) que busca entender como ocorrem as percepções e respostas das pessoas ao utilizarem sistemas computacionais com a intenção de criar produtos que, além de fáceis, úteis e seguros, sejam também cativantes, engajadores e divertidos de usar. Para tal ela usa conhecimento multidisciplinar, incluindo as áreas da Psicologia, do Design e da Engenharia.

A definição formal da UX (aqui em tradução livre) vem do item 2.15 da norma [ISO 9241-210:2010(en)](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:9241:-210:ed-1:v1:en) (*Ergonomics of human-system interaction — Part 210: Human-centred design for interactive systems*):

> "*as percepções e respostas de uma pessoa que resultam do uso ou da
>   antecipação do uso de um produto, sistema ou serviço*"

### UX vs Usabilidade x UI

A Usabilidade é o conceito mais tradicional dentro da IHC. Ela trata da *facilidade de uso* de um produto por um utilizador humano. Por isso inclui aspectos de:

1. **Ergonomia**: O indivíduo é capaz de usar o produto pelo período intencionado sem desconforto? Os controles se ajustam adequadamente aos seus membros? As informações são transmitidas de forma que sejam perceptíveis pelos seus sentidos?
2. **Segurança**: O produto induz o indivíduo a erro? O produto previne que erros sejam cometidos? Erros cometidos podem ser facilmente tratados?
3. **Praticidade**: Os objetivos a serem alcançados são claros? Há feedback apropriado sobre as ações realizadas? A tarefa intencionada é fácil de ser executada? Se sim, o quão efetiva é a sua execução em alcançar os objetivos?
4. [Entre outros...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27099/o-que-s%C3%A3o-princ%C3%ADpios-de-usabilidade).

Já a UX trata da relação subjetiva entre produto e utilizador. Os objetivos são criar produtos que sejam agradáveis, divertidos, motivadores, esteticamente aprazíveis, que permitam a expressão da criatividade, e que recompensem e estimulem o utilizador emocionalmente. Isso é buscado ao se considerar os [fatores humanos do utilizador](http://videolectures.net/chi08_kieras_phc/), além de um mero componente físico e cognitivo em um sistema.

A Usabilidade então faz parte da UX? Claro que sim. Produtos utilizáveis não serão necessariamente prazerosos, mas um produto que não é fácil de utilizar dificilmente fornecerá uma experiência agradável. Aliás, [já foi demonstrado](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-69/paper01.pdf) que para que as pessoas possam apreciar um produto, elas primeiro precisam obter altos níveis de eficiência, efetividade e satisfação (no sentido de atingir seus objetivos com o produto), e isso tudo requer que ao menos elas sejam capazes de entender como um produto funciona.

E a UI (User Interface), onde entra? Bom, o design de interfaces também é uma área importante, e que faz muita interseção com a usabilidade e a UX. Isso é natural, afinal a interface é o meio pelo qual o utilizador usa o sistema. Um botão precisa não somente ser funcional (isto é, fazer o que deve ser feito quando for clicado), mas também ser fácil de ser entendido como um botão (usabilidade) e auxiliar na produção de uma experiência agradável (ser bonito faz parte da UX). De qualquer forma, o design de interface se trata mais de um aspecto de construção (isto é, de engenharia), pois é a implementação que suporta o que é estudado e avaliado pela usabilidade e pela UX.

Por isso, UI e usabilidade são estágios necessários para se alcançar a UX (a fonte do gráfico é o livro [*Designing Pleasurable Products*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415298873)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que essas fronteiras não são necessariamente exatas. Cada tipo de produto pode requer mais ou menos relevância em um aspecto específico. Na imagem abaixo, baseada no mesmo texto referenciado anteriormente, o eixo horizontal vai de produtos mais "sérios" (do tipo que se usa em escritórios para resolver problemas) a produtos menos "sérios" (do tipo de jogos digitais). As duas categorias inferiores são relativas ao design de interfaces e à usabilidade, pois tratam de fazer um produto que primeiramente funciona (efetividade), em segundo lugar funciona da melhor maneira possível (eficiência). A terceira categoria ainda trata da usabilidade, pois satisfação também é a ausência de desconforto e a facilidade de se utilizar. Mas já permite o caminho para a categoria superior, que é diretamente ligada às preferências, memórias e demais fatores afetivos do utilizador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Resposta completíssima. Achei o gráfico Produtos de Escritórios / Jogos de Computador muito interessante, aliás! =)

Comment: Ué? Nesse último gráfico mostra Efetividade e Eficiência maiores em Produtos de "Escritório" e vão decaindo em Jogos de Computador. Concordo. Mas também mostra Satisfação e Fatores afetivos diminuindo em Jogos de Computador, o que me causou estranheza. Se a legenda Jogos de Computador do gráfico estivesse no topo à direita ia melhorar o entendimento.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre Eu creio que você interpretou o gráfico de forma equivocada. Ele trata da importância *relativa* de cada um desses fatores, de forma que as linhas são meramente separadores e não funções lineares (no parágrafo anterior consta "*Observe que essas **fronteiras** não são necessariamente exatas*"). O eixo de variação entre o tipo de produto é o horizontal, enquanto que o eixo vertical é a importância relativa de cada fator para o produto. Considere a área de cada fator que talvez fique mais fácil de entender. :)

Answer (score 19):

UX é uma área do conhecimento que estuda a interação dos usários com o produto ou objeto seja ele um software ou dispositivo físico com o objetivo de facilitar seu uso. Em outras palavras a UX 'pensa' em como o usuário deve utilizar o objeto, como comunicar seus conceitos e funcionalidades através da interface sem a leitura prévia de um manual inteiro.

Vários aspectos são levados em conta para tornar o produto mais agradável e simples de uso. Algumas técnicas usadas vão desde definir o público alvo que vai desde o uso *personas*, entrevistas com possíveis usuários reais para coletar informações de como as 'cobaias' entendem, percebem, quais dificuldades tem ao usar/analisar o produto/modelo.

UX usa bastante dos conhecimentos da psicologia cognitiva, alguns exemplos de uso são analisar a carga de trabalho requerida para interação de uma tela, definir um vocabulário adequado para que instruções (labels) fiquem de fácil compreensão para o público alvo, definir controles adequados para as tarefas.

**Relacionada:**

[Muitas telas ou uma tela com muitas informações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56308/91)

Comment: E além disso, entra o Design de Interação, que não é bem design mas que abrange todos os métodos de pesquisas e interações, tanto homem-computador quanto homem-homem. É uma área muito bacana de estudar.

Comment: **[...] UX 'pensa' em como o usuário deve utilizar o objeto[...]**. Seria tão bom se o usuário "pensasse" igual a UX :p

Comment: @Randrade Não necessáriamente (apesar de já ter sofrido na mão de alguns usários) se o usuário não pensa da forma que foi planejado pode significar que os designers projetaram algo que não atende os objetivos de forma prática então o usuário tente realizar a tarefa de forma mais prática ou performatica. O outro motivo seria a falta conhecimento ou dificuldade em interpretar o modelo proposto. Um exemplo dessa dificuldade foi a interface metro do windows 8 que removeu o botão iniciar e deixou muita gente perdida. É sempre importante ter o feedback dos usuários.

Comment: Claro, concordo plenamente :p

Answer (score 7):

> **Experiência do usuário**
>
> Experiência do usuário (EU), do inglês user experience (UX), envolve
>   os sentimentos de uma pessoa em relação à utilização de um determinado
>   produto, sistema ou serviço. A experiência do usuário destaca os
>   aspectos afetivos, experienciais, significativos e valiosos de
>   interação humano-computador e propriedade do produto. Além disso,
>   inclui as percepções de uma pessoa dos aspectos práticos, tais como a
>   utilidade, a facilidade de utilização e a eficácia do sistema. A
>   experiência do usuário é de natureza subjetiva, pois é sobre a
>   percepção e pensamento individual no que diz respeito ao sistema. A
>   experiência do usuário é dinâmica, pois é constantemente modificada ao
>   longo do tempo, devido à evolução das circunstâncias e inovações.
>
> [Origem: Wikipédia, a enciclopédia livre.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experi%C3%AAncia_do_usu%C3%A1rio)

No curso de Sistemas de Informação, eu tive a matéria de Interação Homem-Computador (IHC), sendo a IHC o conjunto de processos, diálogos, e
ações através dos quais o usuário humano interage com um computador. Podendo ela ajudar a melhorar a experiência do usuário.

Com base nos meus anos de vivência em desenvolvimento de software, digo que a primeira barreira a ser quebrada na utilização de um software é a capacidade psicológica dos usuários em se adaptarem a metodologia empregada no uso comportamental do software.

Um exemplo que posso citar, em um sistema que possuía duas telas de cadastros basicamente iguais, mas com finalidades diferentes. Porém com uma ligeira diferença visual, onde um dos campos estava em posicionamento diferente, sendo solicitado por um determinado usuário que as telas ficassem semelhantes na disposição dos campos, telas que já tinham mais 8 anos e que nunca nenhum outro usuário havia se incomodado com tal diferença.

Então, acredito que um ponto para a UX é o sistema seguir um padrão comportamental. Um ponto a ser levando em consideração no comportamento de um sistema seria nas telas de CRUD os botões, "Salvar", "Excluir", "Cancelar"... estarem sempre posicionados na mesma área.

Answer (score 4):

Segundo a definição do [ISO 9241-210: 2010](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=52075):

> Fornece requisitos e recomendações para princípios e atividades de design centrados no ser humano ao longo do ciclo de vida de sistemas interativos baseados em computador. Destina-se a ser usado por aqueles que gerenciam processos de design, e está preocupado com maneiras pelas quais os componentes de hardware e software de sistemas interativos podem melhorar a interação homem-sistema.

**E como isso pode me ajudar a desenvolver aplicações melhores ou mais agradáveis para os usuários?**

Retirado [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27099/o-que-s%C3%A3o-princ%C3%ADpios-de-usabilidade#27106) as 10 Heurísticas de Nielsen voltadas a Usabilidade.

1. Visibilidade do status do sistema
   O sistema deve sempre manter os usuários informados sobre o que está acontecendo, através de feedback apropriado e em tempo razoável.
2. Correspondência entre o sistema e o mundo real
   O sistema deve falar a linguagem dos usuários, com palavras, frases e conceitos familiares ao usuário, ao invés de termos orientados ao sistema. Siga convenções do mundo real, tornando as informações que aparecem em uma ordem natural e lógica.
3. Controle do usuário e liberdade
   Usuários freqüentemente escolhem algumas funções do sistema por engano e vão precisar sempre de uma “saída de emergência” claramente marcada para sair daquele estado indesejado sem ter que passar por um extenso “diálogo”. Apoio ao desfazer e refazer.
4. Consistência e padrões
   Os usuários não precisam adivinhar que diferentes palavras, situações ou ações significam a mesma coisa. Siga as convenções da plataforma.
5. Prevenção de erros
   Ainda melhor do que boas mensagens de erro é um projeto cuidadoso que impede que em primeiro lugar esse erro possa ocorrer.  Eliminando as condições passíveis de erros ou verificá-las, apresentado aos usuários uma opção de confirmação antes de se comprometerem com uma determinada ação.
6. Reconhecimento em vez de recordação
   Minimizar a carga de memória do usuário tornando objetos, ações e opções visíveis. O usuário não deve ter que se lembrar da informação de uma parte do diálogo para outra. Instruções de uso do sistema devem estar visíveis e serem facilmente recuperáveis quando necessário.
7. Flexibilidade e eficiência de utilização
   Aceleradores – invisíveis para o usuário novato – podem frequentemente acelerar a interação para o usuário experiente, que o sistema pode atender a ambos os usuários inexperientes e experientes. Permitir aos usuários personalizar ações freqüentes.
8. Estética e design minimalista
   Os diálogos não devem conter informações irrelevantes ou raramente necessárias. Cada unidade extra de informação em um diálogo compete com as unidades relevantes de informação e diminui sua visibilidade relativa.
9. Ajude os usuários a reconhecer, diagnosticar e resolver erros
   Mensagens de erros devem ser expressas em linguagem clara (sem códigos), indicar com precisão o problema e construtivamente sugerir uma solução.
10. Ajuda e documentação
    Mesmo que seja melhor que um sistema possa ser usado sem documentação, pode ser necessário fornecer uma ajuda e documentação. Qualquer informação deve ser fácil de se pesquisada, com foco na atividade do usuário, lista de passos concretos a serem realizados, e não ser muito grande.

Answer (score 3):

UX é a experiência do usuário/consumidor ao utilizar um determinado serviço ou produto. No caso do desenvolvimento de aplicações, você consegue implementar os conhecimentos em UX ao entender qual é o perfil do seu cliente (persona), saber o que ele deseja (realmente o que se deseja, não somente atender ao que se pede o briefing, caso se verifique que esta não é a melhor opção), como ele pode fazer para chegar lá (navegação) e se foi fácil ou se foi difícil concluir a ação (experiência). Isso também determina o grau de satisfação do usuário e se vai voltar a utilizar o aplicativo ou não. A clareza é o principal caminho para desenvolver a interface, organizar o conteúdo e garantir o sucesso do projeto.

Fontes/ Recomendações:
[Introdução e boas práticas em UX Design, Fabrício Teixeira](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=vWuCCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Considere incluir na sua resposta Fonte, Artigos e Links de referência.