# O que é non-blocking I/O?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem, io

- O que é *non-blocking I/O*?
- Quais são os usos de uma linguagem com *non-blocking I/O*?
- Quais são as aplicações práticas de *non-blocking I/O*?

Com certeza não entra em questões de opinião, então **eu queria saber os possíveis problemas.**

Comment: Acho que [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona) que pode ser o que procura!

Comment: @Marconi Muito obrigado, eu não sabia que existiam esses termos. Pode ajudar quem deseja procurar a mesma coisa por outros nomes.

Comment: Bom que pode esclarecer @AsuraKhan!

Comment: A resposta já está bem completa, só queria complementar que o termo `non-blocking` significa que a função não bloqueia a `Thread`, ou seja a execução na Thread atual continua sem que a tarefa esteja completa, e não se aplica somente a I/O. Isso só é possível com algum tipo de paralelismo. Em contrapartida, em uma função `blocking` a próxima linha só é executada quando a atual terminar sua tarefa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> O que é non-blocking I/O?

É a capacidade de fazer operações de entrada e saída (**acessar sistema de arquivos, banco de dados, rede, servidores, etc.**) sem que a aplicação fique impedida de executar outras coisas em paralelo.

É muito comum que entrada e saída demore "bastante" por causa do hardware que controla essa operação, mas quase não consome processamento, seria um desperdício não deixar a aplicação fazer outras coisas, então algumas [técnicas podem ser aplicadas para paralelizar a execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101), cada uma atendendo uma necessidade diferente. A mais popular atualmente é a [assincronicidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124283/101).

Aplicações bloqueantes são especialmente ruins quando está fazendo interação com o usuário.

Há casos que até a operação feita em um servidor pode ser prejudicada pelo bloqueio e fazer o usuário receber a informação atrasada.

Pode haver operações que bloqueiam opostamente. Imagine que uma aplicação fique esperando o usuário digitar algo. Normalmente é uma operação bloqueante. Mas não precisa ser, há como permitir que outras operações sejam realizadas em paralelo, o chamado "em *background*.".

De forma geral é vantajoso para melhorar a [experiência do usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182537/101).

> Quais são os usos de uma linguagem com non-blocking I/O?
> Quais são as aplicações práticas de non-blocking I/O?

Essa característica é apenas um ponto específico da linguagem. Muitas vezes tem mais a ver com a biblioteca do que com a linguagem.

Qualquer operação no momento que há interação diretamente com o usuário, seja por console, GUI, browser, etc., se for bloqueante impede o usuário fazer outras tarefas, não dá nem para usar o teclado. Mais ainda, o sistema pode parar de responder, e não só o usuário pode tentar fechá-lo, mas até mesmo o sistema operacional pode fazer isso preventivamente.

Então se vai fazer uma operação mais longa, faça ela não bloqueante, assim no momento que a operação está esperando a resposta do hardware de e/s a CPU continua livre para fazer outras coisas.

Se fizer um *loop* esperando a resposta ele provavelmente será bloqueante. Se criar um sistema de eventos e notificações ([padrão Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101)) economiza muito processamento. O código diz que quer ser avisado quando a operação terminar e tiver uma resposta, assim ele não precisa ficar repetindo a pergunta se já tem uma resposta ou não. É muito mais inteligente.

Forma por laço:

```
pede pra fazer algo
tá pronto?
tá pronto?
tá pronto?
tá pronto?
tá pronto?
tá pronto?
tá pronto?
tá pronto?
.
.
.
em algum momento responde "sim" e continua daqui
```

Código inteligente:

```
faça seu trabalho e me avise quando terminar -> (outra operação demorada executa, notifica)
terminou, continuo daqui
```

Olha a diferença de trabalho.

Com isso o processador não fica trabalhando pra controlar o laço e fica livre pra atender outras demandas. Obviamente só fazendo isso não paraleliza nada, o paralelo pode ocorrer com processos, *threads* ou algum controle da linguagem ou biblioteca, tais como *polling*, *event flags*, *signals*, *green threads*, *callback functions*, *channels*, *registred I/O*.

As linguagens que possuam um mecanismo para não bloquear a execução pode facilitar muito a execução de várias requisições simultâneas em servidores sem desperdiçar recursos porque está bloqueado ou gerenciando a concorrência, resultando no final uma capacidade de atendimento muito maior.

Especialmente em servidor web é comum fazer mais acesso de E/S do que processamento, há vantagem em fazer dessa forma, e é por isso que quase todas linguagens modernas (algumas nem tão modernas assim) possuem mecanismos em si própria ou na biblioteca que permite realizar operações não bloqueantes.

- [Paralelismo e Simultaneidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre comunicação assíncrona e síncrona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51268/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).