# Interface UX em Delphi

Tags: delphi, engenharia-de-software, interface, layout

Trabalho como UX designer, agora tenho que desenvolver uma interface boa para o sistema em Delphi da empresa.

Posso fazer animações e alterações, como eu fazia na parte web?

Comment: Você pode fazer essas animações e interações assim como fazia em JS, porém deve fazer esses elementos interagirem em Delphi, pois os elementos de apresentação são renderizados no próprio ambiente de desenvolvimento server-side, logo não existe HTML e JS quando se está desenvolvendo em INTRAWEB (framework web de delphi).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, pode. Como é uma linguagem que acessa o sistema operacional nativamente pode fazer tudo e muito mais.

Note que não é a linguagem que fornece esta capacidade, é o sistema operacional e a biblioteca da linguagem oferece um acesso facilitado.

Mas é bem diferente do que se faz para web. Até mesmo a UX deveria ser diferente. Você como *designer*  de UX deve saber que tudo precisa ser adaptado ao usuário que efetivamente usará aquilo e na atividade específica. O que é bom para uma mídia não é bom para outra, o que serve para uma atividade é um complicador para outra, o que agrada um público desagrada outro. Não tente reproduzir o que fazia na web, procure o caminho adequado para o desktop ou mobile.

UX não tem a ver com animações, na maior parte das vezes, pelo menos não diretamente, tem a ver com a experiência, como o próprio nome diz. É comum animação deixar algo engraçadinho e piorar a experiência, ou seja não se está fazendo UX e sim entretenimento. A animação pode ser usada para melhorar a experiência, e isto não ocorre em qualquer situação.

Sinceramente quando vejo este tipo de pergunta fico um pouco apreensivo porque provavelmente é melhor a pessoa não fazer isto. Quando o trabalho a ser feito é complexo, depende de profundo conhecimento técnico e experiência para realizá-lo adequadamente, uma pergunta tão básica liga o sinal de alerta. O menor dos seus problemas é saber o que foi perguntado. Você tem uma longa jornada pela frente.

Por exemplo, terá que decidir que *framework* utilizará. A não ser que já decidiram por você, aí a pergunta perderia o sentido. Pode usar o estilo mais tradicional de aplicações desktop ([VCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library)), ou o jeito que é considerado mais moderno, que permite mais personalização de visual e ações, e é programado de uma forma mais parecida com a web ([FireMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireMonkey)), mas que não quer dizer que ele não tenha suas desvantagens.

Não deve ser novo para você, mas [aqui tem uma pergunta com resposta excelente sobre UX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182537/101).

Comment: +1, em especial pelo "Não tente reproduzir o que fazia na web, procure o caminho adequado para o desktop ou mobile.", até porque UX em aplicação nativa é melhor do que web na maioria esmagadora dos casos (quando feita por profissionais). O único ponto de fricção é "instalar" a primeira vez a aplicação, o que não custa nada se é algo que se usa rotineiramente (e, novamente, se for bem feita - mas ainda assim é melhor do que uma aplicação web que depende de você trocar de browser pra funcionar).